# .onReceive do not work when @Published property is changed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a @Published property in ViewModel and .onReceive in View. When my @Published var changes the .onReceive is not even executed.

View is the list of vaccinations. If user clicks "plus button" the new view is pushed. When user clicks on "add new vaccination" the `uploadVaccination` function is called. It is changing the `@Published var didUploadVaccination` to `true` and dismissing the "add new vaccination" view. The previous view has `.onReceive(uploadViewModel.$didUploadVaccination)` at the end so i think it should work, when just dismissed view changed it to "true". But it do not work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
class UploadVaccinationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var didUploadVaccination = false
    let service = VaccinationService()
    
    func uploadVaccination(medicineName: String,
                           lot: String,
                           expirationDate: String,
                           applicationDate: String,
                           comment: String) {
        service.uploadVaccination(medicineName: medicineName,
                                  lot: lot,
                                  expirationDate: expirationDate,
                                  applicationDate: applicationDate,
                                  comment: comment) { success in
            if success {
                self.didUploadVaccination = true
            } else {
                // show errors here...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct VaccinationsListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = VaccinationsViewModel()
    @StateObject var uploadViewModel = UploadVaccinationViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // ...
        }
        .onReceive(uploadViewModel.$didUploadVaccination) { success in
            if success {
                viewModel.fetchUserVaccinations()
                print("success")
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to change `viewModel` to be `@StateObject` similar to `uploadViewModel`. For further explanation, see the linked duplicate target.

Comment: @DávidPásztor your answer is correct. Please post it.